# special driver to connect to sql server 2008 express

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I'm a java newbie, want to test out some hibernate goodies!

I have netbeans installed, and I included the Hibernate libraries.

I then created a new package named Model.

I will drop my Class and xml config files in there.

Do I need a special library to connect to sql server? (windows machine)

Comment: If you add a "java" tag, you'll get a lot more answers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you'll need a JDBC library that talks to Microsoft SQL Server. [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) used to be my first choice but the Microsoft JDBC driver has come a long way and I'd recommend using that. You can download it from [this site](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=99b21b65-e98f-4a61-b811-19912601fdc9&displaylang=en).

You'll also need to follow [these instructions](http://softwaresalariman.blogspot.com/2007/04/jdbc-to-sql-server-express.html) to get the two talking to each other as SQL Server express doesn't listen to TCP by default and uses Windows Authentication Mode.

Have a look at these two URLs for examples of your hibernate.cfg: An [explanatory Blog Entry](http://www.codeweblog.com/hibernate-cfg-xml-configuration-file-including-the-primary-key-generation-strategy-introduction/) and a [JavaRanch Question](http://www.coderanch.com/t/476068/Object-Relational-Mapping/java/hibernate-cfg-xml).

Comment: what would the hibernate.cfg.xml look like?